# [testcafe].click hyperlink inside body mail for activation link not work

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

i try to do automate just for clickin hyperlink that will redirect and trigger to new tab for activation but it doesn't work, already try using selector and xpath

here is from inspect

```
<a title="Activation" href="<base_url>?activation_token=k6ZkSyodTa2AXyv73Z5Z%2Fg" target="_other" rel="nofollow" xpath="1">ACTIVATE</a>
```

and here is my simple code

```
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe'
import xPathToCss from 'xpath-to-css'
import XPathSelector from './xpath-selector'
fixture('test 2').page('https://www.mailinator.com/v3/#/#inboxpane')
test.only('click link activation', async t => {
    const activateLink = Selector('body:nth-child(2) p:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)')  
    await t.click(activateLink) // keeps failing
})
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "it didn't work"? What is the behavior that you're seeing? What is the error message you're receiving? Have you tried running this in the console in the browser and had success (trying to identify the element and then clicking it)?

Comment: You need to inspect the page content and determine which selector reliably determines the desired element. It is better to use unique class names or an element's text for it than an element's index in the child node collections. For example, you can use t.click('[title="Activation"]') or t.click(Selector('a').withText("ACTIVATE")) if there are no other such activation links on the page.   Or you can use the TestCafe Studio which automatically generates selectors during test recording.

Comment: @agoff i mean selecter that i am using is not working, already try with selector and xpath too, the error is element is not found on DOM tree

Comment: @Shurygin.Sergey still not working, as of now i am using vs code IDE
`code`
1) The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.
       > | Selector('[title="Activation"]')

         19 |test.only('coba klik email verification', async t => {
         20 |    await t.typeText(searchBoxInput,'isadore', { paste:true, speed: 0.1 })
         21 |    await t.click(goBtn)
         22 |    await t.click(checkEmailVerification, { speed: 0.2 })
       > 24 |    await t.click(activateLink)
         28 |})

Comment: I checked other messages on the `mailinator` site. It looks like the message body is in the iframe with id="msg_body". If my assumption is correct, you need to execute `await t.switchToIframe('#msg_body')` method before clicking the link ([https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/switchtoiframe.html](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/switchtoiframe.html))

Comment: @AlexKamaev add this await t.switchToIframe('#msg_body') before t.click, it works thanks a lot bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by adding `await t.switchToIframe('#msg_body')`.